# Docker "command not found" after reinstallation

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, docker

I am using Mint 19.2, based on Ubuntu 18.

I uninstalled using `apt purge` & then deleting the folder. Finally, reinstalled Docker using the commands from the [official site](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

However when I run the command `docker -v` or `sudo docker -v`, I get the response:

`command not found: docker`

When I run the command:
`sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`,
I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
containerd.io is already the newest version (1.2.10-3).
docker-ce-cli is already the newest version (5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

[image]

How can I rectify this & make docker accessible globally?

Comment: Does `sudo docker -v` return anything?

Comment: @kemotep no. Still command not found.

Comment: To be clear, you followed all the steps specified in [this link](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) from your post and `sudo docker run hello-world` does not work either? If you note on that page it says that untested and unsupported ports of docker are not expected to work. If you follow [this advice for installing docker on Mint](https://linuxhint.com/install_docker_linux_mint/) you need to add the Ubuntu repos for this to work. Have you done that?

Comment: @kemotep Yes, I installed using Ubuntu version 'Bionic', based of which, Mint is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was that there was conflict & the system had'nt removed docker properly, even though [I followed the instructions as per the official site](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine---community).

However, what worked for me was purging everything docker related.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose
```

Then I removed the docker folder from `/var/lib` folder.

Rebooted for surety. [Then reinstalled as per the official docs again.](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine---community)

And after reboot again, it worked.

Dont forget, `docker-compose` needs to be installed separately.